# DB table relations in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I'm creating a database for my ASP.NET project in Visual Studio 2015. I created tables and now I would like to relations between them.

How can I create relations 1:1, 1:n and m:n? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zed0k41d.aspx ?

Comment: Yes, I did. I haven't anything like that there. I'm creating a DB in SQL Database Project and then add it to ASP .NET application. But now I need to know how to create relations.